# Get data from ember data bind it to a widget in view

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a router that returns data from the data model.

I want to use this data to bind it to a widget in a view.

Model:

```
myApp.Unit = DS.Model.extend({
    active: DS.attr('boolean'),
        allowdecimals: DS.attr('boolean'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    count: DS.attr('number'),
});
```

Router:

```
myApp.EunitsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
        return this.store.find('unit');
  },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        controller.set('units', model);
    },
  actions: { ...
```

In the view I expect an object formated as follows:

```
[ {"id": 1,"active": true,"allowdecimals": true,"name": "Pint","count": 8},
  {"id": 2,"active": true,"allowdecimals": true,"name": "Each","count": 8},
  ...]
```

What I am getting now in the view is an object:`<DS.RecordArray:ember400>`

View:

```
var source10 = {
    datatype: "array",
    datafields: [
        { name: 'id' },
        { name: 'name' },
        { name: 'allowdecimals' },
        { name: 'active' },
        { name: 'count' }
    ],
    localdata: controller.get('units')
};

var dataAdapter10 = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source10);

$("#eunits_grid").jqxGrid({
    pageable: true,
    theme: 'energyblue',
    autorowheight : true,
    rowsheight : 50,
    pagesize: 10,
    source: dataAdapter10,
    ....
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="eunits">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h3 class="page-header">Edit Units</h3>
    {{#if adding}}
      {{view AddnewunitView}}
    {{/if}}
    {{view UnitsView id='eunits_grid'}}
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: can you add the template code where your view is. It looks like you are just calling {{model}} in your view, and ember is printing that model which is <DS.RecordArray:ember400>.

Comment: what are you trying to show in the view? specifically.

Comment: I am not planning on render the <DS.RecordArray:ember400> in the template. load the data in in a view, I want to bind the content to a jqgrid which is all javascript.

Comment: I have updated the post with the view

Comment: My plan is to bind the grid with ember data to reduce server trips

Comment: in your view, if you do `Ember.Logger.log(localdata);` and check the console you should see the record array there and be able to view it. All that data you expect should be within that record array.